# How to upload image to AWS S3 from React Native? Error 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

So I am trying to upload an image to S3 from my React Native code but I am getting a 403 error? I have amplify and have connected it to a user that has admin permissions but it is still not working.

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';

Storage.put('test.txt', 'Hello')
            .then (result => console.log(result))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And my configure is:
[image]

And the error that I am getting is:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a try by adding the contentType at the time of uploading the file.

```
Storage.put('test.txt', 'Private Content', {
    level: 'private',
    contentType: 'text/plain'
})
.then (result => console.log(result))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Check out the issue discussion at https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1094

Comment: @smallzZz8 There must be a permission issue with the s3 bucket.